# list2=[1,2], list1=list2, del list2, then why print(list1) still have [1,2] output?

Tags: python, list

I am running the following code:

```
list2=[1,2]
list1=list2
del list2
print(list1)
```

I wonder why [1,2] is the output? As in my understanding, the name of a list is the name of a memory location where the list is stored, as list2 has been deleted, list1 shall does not exist anymore as well.

Answer (score 1):

`del list2` does not delete a list, but rather it removes the variable (that is the association between the name `list2` and the list value it references).

Thus the value that `list1` refers to is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in Python are just names that point to an object in memory. They are references. When you say:

```py
list1=list2
```

You are just creating another name called `list1` that points to the list object.

You can use https://pythontutor.com/ website to visualize this:

[image]

Now when you execute the line 3, the reference(the name) `list2` is deleted. `del` keyword only deletes the references not the objects:

[image]

There is still a name(variable) `list1` that points to the list object. By deleting that, there is no other reference to the list and that object will be garbage collected.

Comment: Thank you! The visualisation is quite straight-forward and helpful!